# getting error while restoring backup file in raven DB

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio, ravendb-http

I am trying to restore backup file locally using command prompt as below:

```
Raven.Server.exe -src E:\OTUmbraco\OTWDatabases\UAT_RavenDB  -dest E:\OTUmbraco\OTWDatabases\DB\RavenDB  -restore
```

And I am getting error as below:

```
Esent Restore: Failure! Could not restore database!
Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentBadLogVersionException: Version of log file is not compatible with Jet version
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err)
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetRestoreInstance(JET_INSTANCE instance, String source, String destination, JET_PFNSTATUS statusCallback)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.Backup.RestoreOperation.Execute()
Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentBadLogVersionException: Version of log file is not compatible with Jet version
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err)
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetRestoreInstance(JET_INSTANCE instance, String source, String destination, JET_PFNSTATUS statusCallback)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.Backup.RestoreOperation.Execute()
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Restore(String backupLocation, String databaseLocation, Action`1 output, Boolean defrag)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Restore(RavenConfiguration configuration, String backupLocation, String databaseLocation, Action`1 output, Boolean defrag)

   at Raven.Server.Program.RunRestoreOperation(String backupLocation, String databaseLocation, Boolean defrag)
```

Can any one help me to solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to restore this on an older version of Windows than the source is?
For example, the server is Windows 2012 and you are trying to restore on Windows Vista?

Comment: yes. our client is running this on Windows server and i am trying to restore it on windows 7

Answer (score 1):

You cannot go back in the windows version when using RavenDB with Esent.

Comment: I'm getting this when attempting to migrate data from my dev env (Windows 10 Pro) into production (Windows Server 2012 R2). Is that a supported migration path?

Comment: @Ayende Rahien Is it ok to go foward? windows server 2012 to 2022?

Comment: Yes, forward is okay. But note that RavenDB itself that uses Esent is now out of support. Please upgrade to a modern version